# Find comment or answer about notation

Tags: support, specific-question, comment, answers, deleted-questions

If I remember correctly I asked a question during spring 2020 about group theory or algebra and somebody wrote that they had an informal symbol for a generalized operation (I think it looked similar to the direct sum symbol). Now maybe I deleted the question but it could still be visible for an admin perhaps. Is it possible to find it again or to find which was the symbol that someone used for a generalized operation in group theory or algebra?

Comment: I think it's https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774061/is-there-a-general-operator-symbol

Comment: ^^^ which is easy to find by searching, e.g. `user:5602 is:question xyz` for `xyz = operator` or `symbol` (you can also use `me` instead of your userid).

Comment: Or by typing *rosencrantz operation site:math.stackexchange.com* into Google.